# Как отловить нажатие клавиши совместно с кликом по кнопке QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt

Для совершения действия в программе пользователю выскакивает вопросительный Messagebox, в котором необходимо выбрать ДА совместно с зажатой клавишей CTRL.
Код:

```
QMessageBox mb(QMessageBox::Question, kCaption, msg, QMessageBox::NoButton, nullptr);
QPushButton *yesButton = mb.addButton(QString::fromLocal8Bit("Да"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
QPushButton *noButton = mb.addButton(QString::fromLocal8Bit("Нет"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
mb.exec();

if (mb.clickedButton() != yesButton || !QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier))
    return;
```

Однако, программа не отлавливает зажатую клавишу CTRL.
Зато, если завершить месседжбокс нажатием ENTER+CTRL, код срабатывает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас здесь беда в условии, а конкретно - в логическом **ИЛИ**. Замените его на **И**, то есть `||` на `&&`.

Старайтесь не усложнять себе жизнь и пишите требуемую "истину" внутри фигурных скобок, следующих сразу за условием, а всё остальное отдельно:

```
if(mb.clickedButton() == yesButton
    && QApplication::keyboardModifiers()
        .testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier)) {

    // Здесь нажата клавиша CTRL, плюс кнопка "Да".

} else {
    // Здесь любая иная вариация.
}
```

Ежели нужно наоборот:

```
if(!(mb.clickedButton() == yesButton
    && QApplication::keyboardModifiers()
        .testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier))) {

    // Здесь любая иная вариация.

} else {
    // Здесь нажата клавиша CTRL, плюс кнопка "Да".
}
```

Иногда условия превращаются в гигантскую и трудночитаемую лесенку. В этом случае никто не мешает разбить их на составляющие с той лишь целью, чтобы просто упростить понимание:

```
const bool has_button = (mb.clickedButton() == yesButton);

const bool has_modifier
    = QApplication::keyboardModifiers()
        .testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier);

if(has_button && has_modifier) {
    // Здесь нажата клавиша CTRL, плюс кнопка "Да".

} else {
    // Здесь любая иная вариация.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, и я уже как только не пробовал строить лесенки, однако срабатывает только лишь при совместном нажатии Enter и CTRL.